# SenchaTouch 2 - Using Navigation View

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, sencha-touch-2

I am new to Sencha Touch development and trying to develope an app using it. I have been reading its docs and examples. I would like to know what is a best approach to start an app based on following scenario.

LoginView to start the app and then a navigation view.

I am struggling to figure out whether to use NavigationView or Card(for login) + Navigation View(for rest) or any other approach.

If i start with NavigationView then back button appears on top which i don't want to show on second view. dont know how to hide it so can i use something like Card(for login) + Navigation View.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: This might hide the back button navigationView.getNavigationBar().getBackButton().hide();

Comment: Just create you navigation view, then checks whether you need a login screen or not. If you need one, then just create a fullscreen panel on top of the navigation view (use css z-index for that). Then when the user logs in, just make these panel fade away and destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a login view.

Do your ajax request from your login view.

If successful login then you can do something like this:

```
Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(Ext.Viewport.getComponent('mainPanel'), { type: 'slide'});
```

That will animate your mainPanel and slide it into the view. Assuming your 'mainPanel' is your navigation view. The navigation view will start at its default position with no back button. You can now push views into your navigation view.

From a controller:

```
config: {
    refs: {
        mainPanel: 'main'
    },

    control: {
        "list": {
            itemtap: 'onListItemTap'
        }
    }
},

onListItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, options) {
    var myNewView = Ext.create('MyApp.view.Testview');
    this.getMainPanel().push(myNewView);
}
```

Later, if you need to, you can switch back to your login view at any time:

```
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(0);
```

or

```
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.Viewport.getComponent('MyLoginpanel'))
```